# How i can make Totals in difficult array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mapreduce

I need help with different task (it different for me, because i newbie in JS)
i have array:

```js
let results = [
    {
        "id": "su-1617788623816",
        "name": "СУ 2 Мельница",
        "dist": "57",
        "results":
        [
            {"crew":"13","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":40271011,"timeP":0,"speed":"111","shod":false,"reason":""},
            {"crew":"52","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":4815050,"timeP":0,"speed":"170","shod":false,"reason":""}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "su-1617788623816",
        "name": "СУ 2 Мельница",
        "dist": "57",
        "results":
        [
            {"crew":"13","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":10271011,"timeP":0,"speed":"111","shod":false,"reason":""},
            {"crew":"52","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":1815050,"timeP":0,"speed":"170","shod":false,"reason":""}
        ]
    }
]
```

I must have result like:

```js
let result = [
    {
        "id": "su-1617788623816",
        "name": "СУ 2 Мельница",
        "dist": "57",
        "results":
        [
            {"crew":"13","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":X1,"timeP":0,"speed":"111","shod":false,"reason":""},
            {"crew":"52","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":X2,"timeP":0,"speed":"170","shod":false,"reason":""}
        ],
        "total":
        [
            {"crew":"13","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":X1,"timeP":0,"speed":"111","shod":false,"reason":""},
            {"crew":"52","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":X2,"timeP":0,"speed":"170","shod":false,"reason":""}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "su-1617788623816",
        "name": "СУ 2 Мельница",
        "dist": "57",
        "results":
        [
            {"crew":"13","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":Y1,"timeP":0,"speed":"111","shod":false,"reason":""},
            {"crew":"52","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":Y2,"timeP":0,"speed":"170","shod":false,"reason":""}
        ],
        "total":
        [
            {"crew":"13","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":Y1+X1,"timeP":0,"speed":"111","shod":false,"reason":""},
            {"crew":"52","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":Y2+X2,"timeP":0,"speed":"170","shod":false,"reason":""}
        ]
    }
]
```

I not have any ideas, the results can be more then 2. On each step i must have total current step + steps before

Comment: What do you mean by "total current step + steps before"? It looks like you just copied from the `results` property to the `total` property, it's not adding anything.

Comment: On first stem i put in total time:x1 on second step i put time: x2+x1 on third i must put time = x3+x2+x1 (x1 = time on first lap, x2=ti,e on second lap.....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array to hold the accumulated times. Then you can create the `time` array by copying the corresponding `results` array and replacing the `time` property with the accumulated times.

```js
let results = [
    {
        "id": "su-1617788623816",
        "name": "СУ 2 Мельница",
        "dist": "57",
        "results":
        [
            {"crew":"13","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":40271011,"timeP":0,"speed":"111","shod":false,"reason":""},
            {"crew":"52","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":4815050,"timeP":0,"speed":"170","shod":false,"reason":""}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "su-1617788623816",
        "name": "СУ 2 Мельница",
        "dist": "57",
        "results":
        [
            {"crew":"13","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":10271011,"timeP":0,"speed":"111","shod":false,"reason":""},
            {"crew":"52","disc":"60414658612aea0018a1f08e","time":1815050,"timeP":0,"speed":"170","shod":false,"reason":""}
        ]
    }
]


let total_time = Array(results[0].results.length).fill(0);

let result = results.map(res => {
  let time = res.results.map((r, i) => {
    total_time[i] += r.time;
    return { ...r, time: total_time[i]
    }
  });
  return { ...res, time: time
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
      results.forEach((ele,index)=>{
let total = results[index].results;
for(let i = 0;i<=index;i++){
results[index].results.forEach((element,index)=>{
total[index].time += element.time;
})

}
results[index].total=total;
    })
```

I guess this should work!

Update :

reference issue was there in above code resolved it in following:

```
var resultsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
resultsCopy.forEach((ele,index)=>{
let total = resultsCopy[index].results;
for(let i = 0;i<=index;i++){
resultsCopy[index].results.forEach((element,index)=>{
total[index].time += element.time;
})

}
results[index].total=total;
    })
```

Comment: Thanks ) i was try something like this, but in both cases i have  total: [circular object Array]

Comment: Hey check this out now there was reference issue which I fixed now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

First define the function:

```
function reducer(acc, item) {
  let totals = !acc.length ? [...item.results] : [
    {...item.results[0], time: item.results[0].time + acc[acc.length - 1].results[0].time},
    {...item.results[1], time: item.results[1].time + acc[acc.length - 1].results[1].time},
  ];
  acc.push({...item, totals});
  return acc;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
let resultWithTotals = results.reduce(reducer, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result[0]["total"] = result[0].results; 

for (let i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
    let newTotal = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[i - 1]["total"]));
    for (let j = 0; newTotal && j < newTotal.length; j++) {
        newTotal[j].time += result[i].results[j].time; // assuming your X1, Y1, X2, Y2 are numbers
    }
    result[i]["total"] = newTotal;
}

console.log(result);
```